# Adding a column to a table by summing the values from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I have a table with Budget and Forecast. But the Actual Sales is from another table.
Both Table have Year and Months(s).

Table A is a detailed Actual Sales with numerous rows.
Table B is a summary of Fcst and Bdg with single rows for each year each month

I need to create a new column in Table B by summing the Values in Table A showing each Year and Month respectively into Table B.

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V1XQ.png)

[Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOmMv.png)

Comment: Actually, no, you don't need to create a new column. what you need is a calendar table and a few measures 
Total Sales = SUMX('Sales', [Quantity] * RELATED('Product'[Sale Price])
You would do similar with Budget.
Then if you have a calendar table, you can add a column from that (like first of month) to rows and [Total Sales] and [Total Budget] to columns... and then you can subtract [Total Sales] - [Total Budget] to get over/under

Answer (score 0):

You can write a measure to achieve this

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM(TableA[Sales]), Filter(ALL(TableA), TableA[Year]= selectedvalue(TableB[Year]), TableA[Month] = selectedvalue(TableB[Month]))
```